# How to reverse an ArrayList using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to reverse an ArrayList collection using PowerShell. Please see example code:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr = @()
$arr.Add("Apple") | Out-Null
$arr.Add("Orange") | Out-Null
$arr.Add("Banana") | Out-Null

# Print the first element
$arr[0]

# Reverse the array
[array]::Reverse($arr)

# Print the first element
$arr[0]
```

The output is `Apple` `Apple` -- I am expecting the output `Apple` `Banana`

What is wrong here?

Comment: An ArrayList is not the same as an array. You could use its `.ToArray()` method to convert into an array and reverse that, but why not simply define `$arr = 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'` ?

Comment: `Array.Reverse()` method expects an `Array` argument. `ArrayList` is not derived from `Array`, so `Array.Reverse()` won't work. You don't get an error because PowerShell converts the `ArrayList` to an `Array` of one element (which is still of type `ArrayList`), when passing it as an argument. That's a disadvantage of PowerShell's convenience. Solution: use `$arr.Reverse()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the static Array.Reverse() method, which can operate on an array, but cannot operate on an ArrayList, because an ArrayList does not inherit from Array.

You could use the reverse method built into the ArrayList:

```
$arrayList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList -ArgumentList (,("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Dan"))

Write-Host "Array list forward:"
$arrayList

Write-Host "Array list backward:"
$arrayList.Reverse()
$arrayList
```

Also, if all of the objects in your list will be the same type, it's probably best to use a generic list instead of an ArrayList. This makes it explicit what type of objects are in the list and prevents the need to cast anything later.

```
$genericList = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$genericList.Add("Alice")
$genericList.Add("Bob")
$genericList.Add("Charlie")
$genericList.Add("Dan")

Write-Host "Generic list forward"
$genericList

Write-Host "Generic list backward"
$genericList.Reverse()
$genericList
```

There is also the option of using a standard array. Which is the best to use if you don't plan on doing insertions or deletions on it. If you do plan on doing those operations, a generic list is far superior in terms of performance and memory use.